# iPad Settings: Populating root.plist dynamically - Can the system manage new items in root.plist?

Tags: iphone, ipad, settings.bundle, root.plist

When looking in Settings on iPad, tap "Mail, Contacts, Calendar". The first entry is Accounts > Add an account... When choosing this, a new pane is shown where I can add a new account which is then added to the list in the first pane.

Now I want to do similar for an app that I'm developing, ie have the system manage new server accounts that the user creates. That is, as the user has entered address and pwd for a new server, this should be added as an item just before my "Add a server..." item.

I have searched for hours now, but all I get are tutorials and forums on PSChildPaneSpecifier in general, which is not enough. I need to be able to take the info entered in that child pane and add it to root.plist as a new item.

Is this at all possible, and if so, where can I read more about it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible for third-party apps. You cannot add dynamic behavior to the Settings bundle.